# Time reversal symmetry and quantum spin Hall effect

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, topological-insulators, time-reversal-symmetry

As it knows the edge states in QSHE are protected by TR symmetry, so any perturbation that are symmetric under time reversal cannot destroy these states.  A key point is that for $T^{2}=-1$ we have a Kramers' theorem, and indeed the  edge states are  Kramers pairs. But $T^{2}=-1$ only for system with  an odd number of particles with half-integer spin, so it must be too hard to get experimentally QSHE system, because the number of electrons is too dirty quantity (our system is connected with leads). But indeed we have these systems in experiment and I don't understand where am I wrong?

Comment: Where have you read that the number of particles has to be odd in order to fulfill a anti-unitary symmetry as time-reversal?

Comment: The TR operator must be antiunitary in any case, but $T^{2} = -1$ only for system with half-integer spin. So if we have an even number of electrons there is no Kramers' theorem

Comment: I don’t see the link between the half-integer spin and the even number of particles needed to satisfy Kramer’s theorem

Comment: See ch.4 in Topological Insulators and Topological Superconductors by  Bernevig & Hughes

Comment: The edge states are essentially single-particle states. A single particle is an odd number of particles.  More accurateley the edge modes   are single *quasiparticle* states, but the same statement holds.

Comment: How this consistent with that for superconductor where quasiparticle is a superposition of electron and hole (Bogoliubov transformation) the TR operator is also $T = i\sigma_{y}K$, and $T^{2} = -1$ ?